# Verizon GSM SIM card for unlocked Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sim-card, gsm

I have an unlocked Samsung Galaxy S2. I bought it from Bangladesh. It has been working well with any Bangladeshi GSM SIM card. I just arrived in USA. Is it possible to get a Verizon GSM SIM card for my phone?

Comment: Verizon is not a GSM carrier, they use CDMA. The only SIM cards they provide are strictly for 4G LTE service, so this phone isn't going to work on their network.

Comment: what about AT&T? or any other carrier that use GSM?

Comment: AT&T and T-Mobile are the two big carriers in the U.S. that use GSM.

Comment: @AlEverett thanks so, I can buy a AT&T or T-Mobile sim card for my unlocked samsung galaxy s2?